# Trigger sms sending based on customized order status in woocommerce

Tags: sms, woocommerce, twilio

I am using [woocommerce twilio extension](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/twilio-sms-notifications/) which allow me to trigger sms based on order status changes in woocommerce. I have added 2 new customized order status - namely Shipping and Delivered. I would like to know what action hook that I can used to hook, to auto send out sms in Twilio.

```
    // Customer order status change hooks
    foreach( array( 'pending', 'failed', 'on-hold', 'processing', 'completed', 'refunded', 'cancelled' ) as $status ) {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_' . $status, array( $this, 'send_customer_notification' ) );
    }
```

Looking at the script of extension, it seems to me I am not able to do that because there is no woocommerce_order_statsus_shipping or woocommerce_order_statsus_delivered that I can hook to.

Any way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't worked with woocommerce specifically, I have done a lot with WP hooks in general. It looks like there are two different ways to catch this one:

```
woocommerce_order_status_.$new_status->slug
```

which *looks* like it gets fired when the order shifts into a particular status and

```
woocommerce_order_status_.$this->status._to_.$new_status->slug
```

which looks like it catches things moving from one specific status and into another specific status. Does that help?

Source:  http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/